# .monaco-editor class overwriting my VSCode Themes' styles

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I was drilling down into the styles of my VSCode theme(2077), because I was trying to change the color of the curly braces in JS  which is a strange brown color.  I found that they were being styled by a class called "**.monaco-editor .ced-1-TextEditorDecorationType25-1**" .  This class did not exist in the CSS of the theme or any theme and would overwrite any changes I tried to make to the theme. When I switched themes the same class persisted across every theme and is overwriting any theme I activate forcing a universal style across all themes.   I know that the monaco editor is used in VSCode but I don't see it affecting other people's VSCode the way it is affecting mine.   **I was wondering how to overwrite or change this so I have control over how the the theme looks?**  Thanks for any help offered!

Comment: Use the intended way of changing themes. There's a field in `settings.json` that lets you override any color; or you could make a custom theme based on the one you use now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the VSCode extension `vscode-jest`? It seems to set `.monaco-editor` classes. Try to disable it, reload and see if the problem persists. I experienced the same with the class `.monaco-editor ced-TextEditorDecorationType4-0` which put an annoying background to "uncovered" source code. These settings look broken: `jest.coverageColors` and `jest.coverageFormatter`.